# busqueda dentro de un Array con Mongoose y NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, busqueda

Estoy desarrollando una app con NodeJS donde tengo definido los siguientes modelos:

```
export const CategoriaSchema = new Schema({
    name:  { type: String, unique: true, required: [ true, 'El nombre es obligatorio' ] },
    state: { type: Boolean,  default: true },
});
export default model( 'Categoria', CategoriaSchema );

// -----------------------------------------------------
export const ProductoSchema = new Schema({
    name:        { type: String, required: [ true, 'El nombre es obligatorio' ] },
    description: { type: String },
    categories:  { type: Array< Schema.Types.ObjectId >, ref: 'Categoria', required: true },
    company:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Empresa', required: true },
    state:       { type: Boolean, default: true },
    img:         { type: String },
    thumbnail:   { type: String },
}); 
export default model( 'Producto', ProductoSchema );
// -----------------------------------------------------
```

Necesito realizar una búsqueda dentro de Producto que me devuelva todos los productos que contengan al menos una categoría contenida en arreglo pasado por parámetro.

He buscado por horas en la documentacion oficial de Mongoose y le he preguntado incluso a bard.google.com y a chatgpt y siempre lo que encuentro es algo similar a esto:

```
    const categoryIds = await searchCategoryIds( term );

    const items = await Producto.find({
        categories : { $in : categoryIds }
    });
```

Lo cual funciona bien cuando `categories` es un String, pero al cambiar `categories` a un Array me devuelve un arreglo vacio.

Les agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar.